# Problem with the configuration for display on a specific screen on Linux with RaspberryPI4

Tags: c, linux, flutter, gtk, gtk3

I'm working on a project with the Flutter API using a RaspberryPI4.

I've been trying every way to get my app to start on the second screen for a while now, I've scoured all the forums and GTK documentation but with no success. My main purpose is to start two different applications (one for each screen).

The file is automatically generated by Flutter with the command: Flutter create .

*Here is the code in question from the file my_application.cc:*

```
FlView* view = fl_view_new(project);  
 gtk_window_fullscreen_on_monitor(window,gtk_window_get_screen(window),2);
 gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(window));
 gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(view));
 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), GTK_WIDGET(view));
```

I tried to change the number of the last parameter of the gtk_window_fullscreen_on_monitor method to 0, 1, 2, but the application always starts on the first screen on startup.

When I run the program (flutter) in terminal, it displays on the correct screen, but I get the following error:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_fullscreen_on_monitor: assertion "gdk_display_get_monitor (gdk_screen_get_display (screen), monitor) != NULL" failed
```

I'm on ARM64 with GTK3.

Comment: Any follow up to your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I found another way. I would still like to understand the problem, because I did not find anything on the subject.

Comment: What did you found as a solution?

Comment: It's not optimal, but I made sure to move the point of origin to the second screen.

Comment: Here is what I did to temporarily fix the problem:

gtk_window_move(window, 1920, 0);

gtk_window_fullscreen(window);

gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(window));